# Is Connect Configuration required for setting up HMAC in envelope-level webhook in DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

I want to use Envelope-level webhook with HMAC Security for notification, I found in the eventNotification object, a field 'includeHMAC' and for using this I need to setup a HMAC keys in connect page. I have generated a new key, but in the doc https://developers.docusign.com/platform/webhooks/connect/setting-up-hmac/
there are steps which asks to include the HMAC signature in connect configuration, I understand this is required if I want to use account-level webhook, for envelope level webhook do I need to create a custom configuration for HMAC security, or generating the key itself is enough?

Comment: Welcome! ***PLEASE check (accept) the best answer to your question. Many thanks!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, HMAC codes (signatures) can be included for envelope-level connect webhooks.

To do so, set the `includeHMAC` attribute to `true` in the `eventNotification` object of the Envelopes:create API call. See the [docs](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/create/#schema__envelopedefinition_eventnotification_includehmac)

However, you need to set up the HMAC keys (secrets) using the Connect section of the eSignature Admin tool. So that means that the account needs to have the Connect feature enabled.

You do not need to set up an account-level Connect configuration.

We have an internal enhancement request CONNECT-2406 to enable the HMAC secrets screen to be available to all customers. Please ask your DocuSign contacts to add your information to that ticket.

Recommended: you can also raise this as an issue via https://feedback.docusign.com

### HMAC alternative

The main alternative to using HMAC to authenticate the webhook notification message is to use Mutual TLS.

### Also

The OP asks:

> Is it possible to enable this via esignature api for every account that uses my integration (app created from the Apps & Keys) and generate the HMAC keys programmatically.

Unfortunately the API for managing HMAC keys is not public.
But you can add your vote to change this! See this [DocuSign feedback item](https://feedback.docusign.com/forums/936834-apis/suggestions/44243853-hmac-signature-for-embedded-signing-results)

Comment: Thanks Larry, It gives me more clarity. My external application allows the user to log into their own docusign account and create envelope and I want to get the envelope status and display in my application. Earlier I did this using an esign api call for every envelope(polling), but I want to make use of envelope level webhook here. Since HMAC requires connect to be enabled. Is it possible to enable this via esignature api for every account that uses my integration( app created from the Apps & Keys) and generate the HMAC keys programatically.

Comment: @R_M_R -- please see updated answer